# Angular5: How to bind events in asynchronously loaded data to datatables

Tags: angular, datatables, event-binding

Am loading the table data through ajax which includes the edit and delete buttons,
and now when I try to access a particular button through event binding it is not working

here is the html part

```
<div class="widget-body no-padding">
<sa-datatable [options]="tableData" paginationLength="true" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-hide="phone"> ID </th>
            <th data-class="expand"> Name </th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet"> Email </th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet"> Role </th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet"> join Date </th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet"> Action </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</sa-datatable>
```

and in the component am loading the data through ajax

```
tableData = {
ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
  this.usersService.getUsers(0).subscribe(data => {
    if(data.success){
        callback({
          aaData: data.data
        });
    } else {
      alert(data.msg);
    }
  },
  error => {
      alert('Internal server error..check database connection.');
  });
},
columns: [ 
    { 
      render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
      }
    },
    {
      data: function (name) { return  name.firstname+ ' ' + name.lastname; }
    }, 
    {data: 'email'},
    {data: 'user_role'}, 
    {data: 'created_at'},
    {          
      render: function (data, type, row) {
        return `<ul class="demo-btns">\
                  <li> <span (click)="edit()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Edit</span></li>\
                    <li> <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Delete</span></li>\
                </ul>`;
      }
    }
],
buttons: [
    'copy', 'pdf', 'print'
]};

edit(){
console.log('Clicked..');}
```

when I load the data through ajax it looks like the dom elements are not created and that's the reason it is not emitting any events. could anyone please let me know how can I listen to the events on click of the button in any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys finally I found the working code after doing few changes using addEventListner here is the code will be useful for someone.

```
tableData: any;
 ngOnInit() {  
    tableData = {
              ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
                this.usersService.getUsers(0).subscribe(data => {
                  if(data.success){
                      callback({
                        aaData: data.data

                      });
                  } else {
                    alert(data.msg);
                  }
                },
                error => {
                    alert('Internal server error..check database connection.');
                });
              },
              columns: [ 
                  { 
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    data: function (name) { return  name.firstname+ ' ' + name.lastname; }
                  }, 
                  {data: 'email'},
                  {data: 'user_role'}, 
                  {data: 'created_at'},
                  {          
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                      return `<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs edit" data-element-id="${row._id}">
                      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</button>`;
                    }
                  }
              ],
              buttons: [
                  'copy', 'pdf', 'print'
              ]
            };

            document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
                let target = <Element>event.target; // Cast EventTarget into an Element
                if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button' && $(target).hasClass('edit')) {
                  this.user_edit(target.getAttribute('data-element-id'));          
                }   
            });

              user_edit(user_id){
                console.log("user edit:" +user_id);
                // Here goes the edit login
              }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented through listening to the events

```
    tableData = {
    ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
      this.usersService.getUsers(0).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.success){
            callback({
              aaData: data.data
            });
        } else {
          alert(data.msg);
        }
      },
      error => {
          alert('Internal server error..check database connection.');
      });
    },
    columns: [ 
        { 
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
              return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
          }
        },
        {
          data: function (name) { return  name.firstname+ ' ' + name.lastname; }
        }, 
        {data: 'email'},
        {data: 'user_role'}, 
        {data: 'created_at'},
        {          
          render: function (data, type, row) {
            return `<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs edit" data-element-id="${row._id}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</button>`;
          }
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]

      };

      ngAfterViewChecked() {

    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
        let target = <Element>event.target;// Cast EventTarget into an Element
        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button' && $(target).hasClass('btn-warning')) {
            this.user_edit(target.getAttribute('data-element-id'));
        }   
    });

  }

      user_edit(userId){
        console.log("user edit:", userId);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

use angular click directive for listening and rendering DOM efficiently.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: tried it will not work since the data is loaded dynamically and the elements will not be listed in the DOM since angular is rendered be content is loaded.